# Can I use Jmeter for testing the performance of the application on IIS server?

Tags: iis, jmeter

I'm using IIS server for my web application. Can I use Jmeter for testing the performance of the application on IIS server?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter supports any web application and it doesn't care about underlying back-end technology as it operates on HTTP protocol level basically sending requests and awaiting for responses.

For ASP.NET applications (if only you aren't testing another application type via ISAPI) there could be some challenges connected with mandatory dynamic parameters like VIEWSTATE or EVENTVALIDATION or whatever. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for workaround on common situations.